# my bot doesnt want to do the commands eventho it is online

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

i tried working on at the code and saw nothing wrong with  the code, i retried multiple times to get it right nothing

this is the code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '^';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('MEMEbot has gone online'); 
})

client.on('message', message => {
   if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

   const args = message.content.slice(prefix.lenght).split(/ +/);
   const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

   if(command === 'ping') {
       message.channel.send('pong!');
   }
});

client.login('my token');
```

Comment: yes i followed a tutorial from codelyon dont judge me ;-;

Comment: Is the callback function of message event being executed? You may add `console.log('onMessage', message.content)` to the callback function to test whether your bot received the message or not.

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo:

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.lenght).split(/ +/);
                                              ^^
```

should be

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
                                              ^^
```